# js set stroke opacity in an html canvas (same rgb, but different alpha)

Tags: javascript, canvas

my code (o is previously defined):

```
colors = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].style.backgroundColor.substring(colorString.indexOf('(') + 1, colorString.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/);
red = colors[0];
green = colors[1];
blue = colors[2];

canvas.strokeStyle = "rgba("+red+","+green+","+blue+","+o+")";
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You can apply only 1 styling (opacity) per set of path commands. Each new path command begins with `beginPath`. So to stroke with 2 opacities you will need 2 sets of path commands.